# Need script for Ubuntu reset? Random server crashes, 3 different servers, all at the same time?

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, virtual-machine, webserver, crash

I manage a number of websites for a bunch of clients.

I use Vultr.com $5 plan 1 CPU 1 GB

Virtualmin

Basic websites with infrequent use. Although it does look like I got a lot of visits from bots.

Anyway each individual client has their own account with their own server for $5.

Randomly, at around 2:26 AM every other day or so, 3 out of 8 servers go down completely. Apache error logs empty of anything serious.

The servers are in no way connected.

the only thing is that all of the configurations are the same of course because I would have the same configuration of course for everyone.

I figured the best way to solve my problem would be to have the Ubuntu Server automatically reboot every single day at 3 am or so, and it hasn't helped at all.

This is extremely confusing.

Also I want to mention that some sites go down less than others. For example I have a very cheap $2. 50 Ubuntu server, running 5 practice sites and that one seems to be every other week, but rarely, despite the RAM and CPU being at 70%+

the most realistic question I could give would be if somebody doesn't know what's going on or what I should look for, is there a script to restart the entire server when it notices that httpd is down?

Comment: Do not take me wrong, given the scenario you describe us of multiple machines having problems at the same time, it would make more sense opening a ticket with them, then asking random strangers on the net. Even more when you are a paying customer.

Comment: I did this, they tell me to run commands that do nothing, and don't produce any results (firewall, IPtables, etc)

Comment: They are your provider, not us. We cannot help much. You either escalate the issue, hire a good consultant to handle the gathering of evidence or get another provider. You have got to escalate to a manager and tell them you are not capable of debugging it further. If they are making you running through their helpdesk scripts with several machines having problems, their helpdesk does not know what they are doing.

Comment: It's an unmanaged VPS, they specifically state they don't help beyond their scope. Is this not why this site exists?

Comment: This site exists to provide Unix answers to specific questions, please lurk for a while and read our FAQ. Our vocation is neither generic helpdesk nor too broad questions. We also are not able to guess your provider problems. I would say that as a paying customer, you need better service and press more that issue with them. That said, we are more than happy to answer you in specific and narrowed down questions to help you improve your knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Usually instances of multiple machines having problems at the same time or hour points to problems higher up in the virtualization environment.

Those 3 VMs might share a common problematic host or storage.

I would file a ticket with your Virtualization provider.